# Get the difference between values at the row level in sas

Tags: sas

The data is basically month on month price of configuration. I wanted to get a trend of the AMOUNT. As to how is the price behaving over a period of 12 months, for each configuration and overall trend.

Proc sql doesn't support "dif" syntax. I am unable to use the regular "do" loop in data-set as this is not really helpful here.

So can anyone help me with this ?

This code is to basically group the data and get a mean price for each configuration in that month.

```
proc sql;

create table c.price1 as 
select 
configuration,
month,
mean(retail_price) as amount format = dollar7.2

from c.price
where 
configuration is not missing 
and month is not missing 
and retail_price is not missing
group by configuration, month;
quit;
```

DATA :

```
Configuration   Month     Amount
1                  1    $370.00
1                  2    $365.00
1                  3    $318.00
1                  4    $355.00
1                  5    $350.00
1                  6    $317.40
1                  7    $340.00
1                  8    $335.00
1                  9    $297.00
1                 10    $325.00
1                 11    $320.00
1                 12    $286.65
2                  1    $320.00
2                  2    $315.00
2                  3    $287.86
2                  4    $305.00
2                  5    $300.00
2                  6    $263.76
```

.......and so on

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Can you please post your desired output? Why can't you use a data step with dif function?

Comment: You can always join a table to itself on condition a.month=b.month-1 and a.config=b.config.

Comment: if i use dif function then how do i control it. In the sense when the config changes from 1 to 2 then i do not want $320-$286.65 (according to the data). I want it to be grouped. So that when the configuration changes, then dif function starts up fresh.

Comment: Look up BY group processing. If first.config then value=.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DIF function in conjunction with BY group processing.

```
Data want;
    Set have;
     By config;

      New_var = dif(amount);

      If first.config then new_var = .;
 Run;
```

Comment: Thanks much! I was breaking my head on the same code. But I was not aware of      "If first.config then new_var = .;" piece of coding. Now everything is sorted :D

Comment: Then you did it wrong somehow. Post your code and log. Also, define grouping.